# JsonSyntaxException while using gsonto add or remove objects

Tags: android, gson

Im using the following code to add a track to favourite

```
 private void addToFavourites(LocalTrack localTrack) {
        SharedPreferences        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor            = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson                     gson              = new Gson();
        int                      imgKey            = 0;
        String                   json              = gson.toJson(localTrack);
        editor.putString("" + imgKey, json);
        editor.apply();
        imgKey++;

    }
```

Im using the following code to remove a track from favourite.

```
private void removeFromFavourites(LocalTrack localTrack){
        ArrayList<LocalTrack>    localTracks       = loadPreferences();
        for (int i = 0; i < localTracks.size(); i++){
            if (localTracks.get(i).getPath().equals(localTrack.getPath())){
                localTracks.remove(localTrack);
            }
        }
        SharedPreferences        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor            = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson                     gson              = new Gson();
        int                      imgKey            = 0;
        String                   json              = gson.toJson(localTracks);
        editor.putString("" + imgKey, json);
        editor.apply();
        imgKey++;
    }
```

Adding a track to favourites works perfectly.
Removing a track from favourites mis aligns the json and hence im getting an error as follows ,

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How can I be able to remove the track from the json without jsonsyntax exception?

**UPDATE:**

```
public static ArrayList<LocalTrack> loadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences     sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.act);
        Gson                  gson              = new Gson();
        Map<String, ?>        allPrefs          = sharedPreferences.getAll();
        String                gsonString        = sharedPreferences.getString("userImages", "");
        ArrayList<LocalTrack> images            = new ArrayList<LocalTrack>();
        if (!allPrefs.isEmpty()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allPrefs.entrySet()) {
                String     json = entry.getValue().toString();
                LocalTrack temp = gson.fromJson(json, LocalTrack.class);
                images.add(temp);
            }
        }
        return images;
    }
```

I have added the load preferences method

Comment: can you also add the ```loadPreferences()``` please?

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 0):

You can you gson to deserialize generic collection:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<LocalTrack>>(){}.getType();
List<LocalTrack> lsLoadTracks = new Gson().fromJson(stringsInSharePref, listType);
```